# csv upload to datatable having comma in column cell as string using C#

Tags: c#, csv

I am using split function to upload csv to datatable, but if it gets comma as a string it separates it as a different column.

```
foreach (var RowItem in GLExtract)
{
    string[] Acctid = (**RowItem.ToString()).Split(',');**

    string glacct = Acctid[70].ToString();
    decimal remitAmt = decimal.Parse(Acctid[47].ToString());
    if (acctno==glacct)
    {
        sum = sum + remitAmt;
        dtflatfile.Rows[x]["field10"] = sum;
    }
}
```

Can you please help me with this??

Comment: Parse it, or try a different format. CSV breaks horribly in these cases or when you have different locales (NL_nl for example uses the semicolon to separate fields).

Comment: Textfieldparser. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Anyone can please help how to parse above code?

Answer (score 0):

Presumably the field containing a comma is quoted.  You can't parse CSV using String.Split on the delimiter in this case.

Either use one of the many third-party CSV parsers that google knows about, or use the [TextFieldParser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser.aspx) class in the Microsoft.VisualBasic namespace of the .NET framework.

Comment: Is there any way to bypass or escape the double questes?

Comment: @Nishant, yes, any decent CSV parser will be able to strip quotes. Google for "TextFieldParser CSV" and you'll find plenty of examples of how to do it with the `TextFieldParser` class.  Or google for ".NET CSV parser" for other third-party alternatives.